# Unlock iPhone device to continue?

Tags: iphone, xcode, unlock

Even if my iPhone is connected using cable and unlocked, it is shows an alert "Xcode 9.3 can not launch app on iPhone because of device is locked". I don't know what to do? Any one have proper solution for this? Please [image: click here]

Comment: restart your xcode and check.i am also sometimes got this problem

Comment: Okay, It worked for me but is there any permanent solution? Because I get this problem so many times and not sure what exact problem is.

Comment: clear cache before every run will reduce this occurrence times.

Comment: clearing cache does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Just replug you iPhone and have another try.

A better option is to use wireless debugging. Open Xcode menu > Window > Devices & Simulators and set your device to debug via network.

Comment: You helped me like an angel

Comment: I am currently having this issue with Wireless Debugging. Enabling this feature does not resolve the problem